# Can we have Flask error handlers in separate module

Tags: python, flask

We are migrating our Flask app from function based views to pluggable views, all working as expected, except the error handlers. I am trying to put all the error handlers in a single module called error_handlers.py and importing it in to the main module. But it is not working. 
Tried searching in Google and find some Git repos following the same way, but it is not working for me, please help me to solve this issue.

```
app
 |
 |__ __init__.py
 |__ routing.py (which has the app=Flask(__name__) and imported error handlers here [import error_handlers])   
 |__ views.py 
 |__ error_handlers.py (Ex: @app.errorhandler(FormDataException)def form_error(error):return jsonify({'error': error.get_message()})
 |__ API (api modules)
      |
      |
      |__ __init__.py
      |__ user.py
```

I am using Python 2.6 and Flask 0.10.1.

Comment: Did you try to import `error_handlers` into `views`?

Comment: No, I have all my views in a module called views.py, will edit the structure now. I am trying to import this into routing.py, which has the Flask instance variable.

Comment: Hi Syed, thanks, I couldn't even import error_handlers in views. I guess it is because I am import views in routing.py and I am imporing error_handlers in views py which imports app from routing.py..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you import `error_handlers` module in `routing.py` as like

```
import error_handlers
```

Better you do import like following as in `routing.py`

```
from error_handlers import *
```

It could be help you:-)

Comment: Sayed, you are correct, but what is the difference?, and it is working only if I imported error_handlers after added url_rules.

Comment: Just thinking, If you import `error_handlers` module as just `import error_handlers`, it will only import error_handler module, it can't use for flask app context. Instead of using `from error_handlers import *` it will import all the things in `error_handlers` module, then flask app context directly used those methods. That's it.

Comment: Is it right if we do "from error_handlers  import *" ? I couldn't do from error_handlers import auth_errorhandler" getting ImportError: cannot import name auth_error.

Comment: Yeah. I saw it. `ImportError: cannot import name auth_error` is because of flask application context problem I think. Using this the decorator wouldn't work properly.

Answer (score 19):

While you can do this using some [circular imports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency), e.g.:

app.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

import error_handlers
```

error_handlers.py

```
from app import app

@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle404(e):
    return '404 handled'
```

Apparently, this may get tricky in more complex scenarios.

Flask has a clean and flexible way to compose an applications from multiple modules, a concept of [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/). To register error handlers using a [`flask.Blueprint`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#blueprint-objects) you can use either of these:

- [`flask.Blueprint.errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) decorator to handle local blueprint errors
- [`flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler) decorator to handle global app errors.

Example:

error_handlers.py

```
import flask

blueprint = flask.Blueprint('error_handlers', __name__)

@blueprint.app_errorhandler(404)
def handle404(e):
    return '404 handled'
```

app.py

```
import flask
import error_handlers

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(error_handlers.blueprint)
```

Both ways achieve the same, depends what suits you better.

Comment: Still I don't understand, why I shouldn't use @app in error_handlers.. Instead of using blueprint I chose Methodviews and views, since I don't want to add more 3dr party plugins more into my app.

Comment: @JohnPrawyn Well, depends what suits you best. If you are okay with circular imports you can continue that way. Blueprints are just a handy way to do app composition. Added a circular imports example too.

Comment: thanks famousgarkin, in my case "import error_handlers" not working whereas  "from error_handlers import * is working, that too I have put this line after I have added all the app.add_url_rule

Comment: I have posted my code in https://github.com/Prawyn/flask_pluggable_views/ please go through the routing.py, and pls correct my if i miss anything...

Comment: @JohnPrawyn That's exactly what I mean by tricky circular imports. You start from `routing`, then import `error_handlers`, then import `routing` again. This way the `routing` module gets executed multiple times, while it matters at what point in the module execution the imports are introduced, resulting in errors such as *AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: user_view* and the need to take extra care to order everything properly. In the end it's convoluted, inflexible and error prone and that's why we have blueprints to help.

Comment: Code displayed above did not work for me. Working code should read `blueprint = flask.Blueprint('error_handlers', __name__)` (underscore added). However a single character edit is not allowed and I didn't see anything else in the answer that needed improvement. :/

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman Interesting, for me works alright with spaces too. Nonetheless, I cannot find an example online that's using spaces, everyone puts underscores, so I updated my code as well. Thanks for pointing out, may come helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, I was looking exactly for how to avoid the circular import. Didn't think about using blueprints for error handling. Just wanted to emphasise the fact that `errorhandler()` becomes `app_errorhandler()` when using blueprint objects instead of the Flask object.

Comment: Not sure what version of Flask this it, but it's definitely deprecated, getting a bunch of errors even copy-pasting

Comment: Like  `AttributeError: module 'error_handlers' has no attribute 'name'`

Answer (score 0):

@NaturalBornCamper said that he was getting errors. I had to google around a bit but this is what I ended up with for now. I tried to reply to his comment but I did not have enough reputation.

My solution followed the blueprints path and having each blueprint have its own templates and static folder as well.

I have it under `src/app/blueprints/errors/handlers.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('errors',
               __name__,
               template_folder='templates',
               static_folder='static', )

@bp.app_errorhandler(404)
def handle404(error):
    return '404 handled'
```

With the following in my init at `src/app/blueprints/errors/__init__.py`:

`from .handlers import bp as errors_bp`

If you want your blueprint to handle its own errors you would do:

`@bp.errorhandler()`

But from my understanding this won't catch some errors because blueprints routes are registered differently so it might behave differently then you expect.

This is what I have as the factory application under `src/app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    from app.blueprints.personal import personal_bp
    from app.blueprints.errors import errors_bp
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.register_blueprint(personal_bp, url_prefix='/') # blueprint for my personal site set to the default route
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)
    return app
```

Then I run the following command to test with it flask from `/src`:

```
> export FLASK_APP=app
> export FLASK_APP=development
> flask run
```