# errorhandler in separate blueprint is not working

Tags: flask, python-3.7

I am currently working on an app using flask. Whenever I am encountering an error, I am raising it using abort, for example abort(404).

I created a new blueprint for error handling, and included the following files in the errors blueprint:

**app/errors/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('errors', __name__)

from app.errors import handlers
```

**app/errors/handlers.py**

```
from app.errors import bp
from flask import jsonify, make_response


@bp.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_error():
    return make_response(jsonify({"error: ", "Not found"}), 404)
```

I also registered the blueprint as follows:

**app/__init__.py**

```
from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)
```

However, when I am encountering the error, I get an HTML response back instead of the JSON response. If I include the errorhandler in the same blueprint as the APIs, it works fine. How do I have a separate error handler blueprint?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This answer explains your solution and works for me:

[Can we have Flask error handlers in separate module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859014/can-we-have-flask-error-handlers-in-separate-module#24859610)

Looks like the only problem in your code is that you're using

`@bp.errorhandler(404)`

And you should be using

`@bp.app_errorhandler(404)`